# Get only specific relations records

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a Client model and Deposits model relation: 
in the Deposits model table, I have column: campaign_id
in the Client model I have:

```
public function deposits()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ClientDeposit::class, 'client_id');
}
```

i do simple query:

---

```
private function relations()
{
    return [
        'deposits',
    ];
}

$query->with($this->relations());

$query->whereHas('deposits', function ($query) {
   $query->where('campaign_id', '2');
})
```

this code returns me Clients with 'campaign_id', '2' with but with deposits with all other campaign_id too

```
clients[0:{deposits: [id: 18507, client_id: 162186, user_id: 22, campaign_id: 2, amount: 100, method_id: null
0: {id: 18507, client_id: 162186, user_id: 22, campaign_id: 2, amount: 100, method_id: null,…}

1: {id: 18505, client_id: 162186, user_id: 22, campaign_id: 2, amount: 100, method_id: null,…}

2: {id: 18506, client_id: 162186, user_id: 22, campaign_id: 10, amount: 100, method_id: null,…}

3: {id: 18498, client_id: 162186, user_id: 22, campaign_id: 3, amount: 100, method_id: null,…}}]
```

I want that the relation in the Client record will return only Deposits with campaign_id 2 an not all other related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query->with([
    'deposits' => function($) {
        $q->where('campaign_id', '2');
    }
])
```